# Subscribing to TeamSystem events

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I trying to subscribe to the "build complete" event of TeamFoundation like it's described in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx. And I'm failing to get anything from team system. Can anyone point to some potential problem areas I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this excellent [blog](http://blogs.conchango.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2006/04/29/3894.aspx) article when I was looking at catching events. It has a template that you can download, it's really easy to get up and running and start learning about what events you can catch.